# hover não funciona

Tags: html5, css3

```css
.csgo-player {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.csgo-player-link {
  width: 40%;
  position: relative;
}

.csgo-player-info {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.csgo-player-link:hover .csgo-player-info {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<li class="csgo-player">
  <a href="#" class="csgo-player-link">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="csgo-player-info">
      <header class="csgo-player-header">
        <h2 class="csgo-player-header__title">arT</h2>
        <span>Andrei Piovezan - IGL</span>
      </header>
      <div class="csgo-player-socials">
        <ul class="csgo-player-social-list">
          <li class="csgo-player-social-item"></li>
          <li class="csgo-player-social-item"></li>
          <li class="csgo-player-social-item"></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="csgo-player-download">Download CFG
                <i class="csgo-player-download__arrow"></i>
             </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Quero que quando der um *hover* no `.csgo-player-link`, o `.csgo-player-info` apareça... Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resumidamente, o problema é que seu HTML está muito mal estruturado.

- O código inicia com um `<li>` avulso;

  - Aqui podemos até considerar que você omitiu o resto do código, mas é apenas uma suposição.
- Você tem uma âncora `<a>` que não é uma âncora;

  - Âncoras são elementos que provem navegação, mas você está usando apenas para ter um `hover`.
- Você tem elementos filhos dentro de uma âncora que não fazem sentido;

  - Lista como filho de âncora? Faz sentido eu clicar sobre a lista e ser redirecionado à outra página? Parece que não é o caso.
  - E o problema principal: uma âncora como filha de outra âncora? Isso não faz o menor sentido.

Reduzindo o seu código ao mínimo verificável você basicamente possui:

```
<a href="//url_A">
    <a href="//url_B">Clique aqui</a>
</a>
```

Se eu clicar em "Clique aqui", irei para a página "//url_A" ou "//url_B"?

```html
<a href="//url_A">
  <a href="//url_B">Clique aqui</a>
</a>
```

Ao inspecionar a página, verá:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É exatamente esse conflito que quebra o seu código. Basta inspecionar a sua página para avaliar qual é o HTML que o navegador processou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que tem nada a ver com o código que você originalmente escreveu.

Para resolver o problema, você terá que corrigir a estrutura do seu HTML para algo que faça sentido, principalmente corrigindo essa âncora que não é âncora.

```css
.csgo-player {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.csgo-player-link {
  width: 40%;
  position: relative;
}

.csgo-player-info {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.csgo-player-link:hover .csgo-player-info {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div href="#" class="csgo-player-link">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="csgo-player-info">
    <header class="csgo-player-header">
      <h2 class="csgo-player-header__title">arT</h2>
      <span>Andrei Piovezan - IGL</span>
    </header>
    <div class="csgo-player-socials">
      <ul class="csgo-player-social-list">
        <li class="csgo-player-social-item"></li>
        <li class="csgo-player-social-item"></li>
        <li class="csgo-player-social-item"></li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#" class="csgo-player-download">Download CFG
                <i class="csgo-player-download__arrow"></i>
             </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pelas especificações HTML, é incorreto usar elemento `<a>` dentro de outro `<a>` como está fazendo. Ao fazer isso, o navegador irá automaticamente fechar o primeiro `<a>`, fazendo com que o segundo `<a>` se torne um elemento separado do primeiro `<a>`, como mostra o print:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Com isso, o seletor `.csgo-player-link:hover .csgo-player-info` se
>   torna inválido.

Neste caso, utilize uma div em vez de `<a>`, e coloque na classe `.csgo-player-link` a propriedade `cursor: pointer` para alterar o cursor do mouse na div para que o usuário perceba que ali há alguma interação:

```css
.csgo-player {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.csgo-player-link {
  width: 40%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer; /*ALTERA O CURSOR*/
}

.csgo-player-info {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.csgo-player-link:hover .csgo-player-info {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li class="csgo-player">
     <div class="csgo-player-link">
       <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="">
       <div class="csgo-player-info">
         <header class="csgo-player-header">
           <h2 class="csgo-player-header__title">arT</h2>
           <span>Andrei Piovezan - IGL</span>
         </header>
         <div class="csgo-player-socials">
           <ul class="csgo-player-social-list">
             <li class="csgo-player-social-item"></li>
             <li class="csgo-player-social-item"></li>
             <li class="csgo-player-social-item"></li>
           </ul>
           <a href="#" class="csgo-player-download">Download CFG
                   <i class="csgo-player-download__arrow"></i>
                </a>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Troca o **a** por **div**; acredito que **a** não tenha características que permitam fazer isso como a **div**. Eu vi isso aqui http://jsfiddle.net/zEJVK/6/

.cp-thumb:hover .cp-hover { display:block; }

```css
.csgo-player {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.csgo-player-link {
  width: 40%;
  position: relative;
}

.csgo-player-info {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.csgo-player-link:hover .csgo-player-info {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<li class="csgo-player">
  <div href="#" class="csgo-player-link">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="csgo-player-info">
      <header class="csgo-player-header">
        <h2 class="csgo-player-header__title">arT</h2>
        <span>Andrei Piovezan - IGL</span>
      </header>
      <div class="csgo-player-socials">
        <ul class="csgo-player-social-list">
          <li class="csgo-player-social-item"></li>
          <li class="csgo-player-social-item"></li>
          <li class="csgo-player-social-item"></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="csgo-player-download">Download CFG
                <i class="csgo-player-download__arrow"></i>
             </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: No exemplo que postou pelo JSFiddle, ao substituir todas as `div.cp-thumb` por âncoras `a.cp-thumb` [funcionará normalmente](http://jsfiddle.net/tp7q04Le/), o que mostra que sua premissa, de que com `<a>` não funciona está equivocada.

Comment: Obrigado pelo exemplo! Eu troquei no código de exemplo da pergunta e funcionou. Nesse cenário específico não funcionou com a e com div sim. Não estudei a fundo o porquê da diferença.

Comment: Se puder por favor tentar fazer funcionar com <a> meu código que está funcionando com <div> na resposta, ficaria grato de entender.

Comment: Leonardo, coloquei a explicação em forma de resposta

Answer (score -1):

É só vc colocar um target para o hover, assim: `.csgo-player-link:hover .csgo-player-info{
display:block;}`Por padrão o target é o proprio elemento.

Comment: E não está exatamente assim no código da pergunta?

Comment: AAh sim , desculpe. Já tentou usar !important ?